# showing bad operands: first is double[] and second is int in the if statement

Tags: java

```
package bank.vip.or.np;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BankVipOrNp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // this is a programm for a bank to determine whether the customer is vip or np
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        double [] balance = new double[100];

        for (int i=0;i<balance.length;i++){

            System.out.println("enter the balance for customer no"+(i+1));
            balance[i]=input.nextDouble();
        }
       
        for (int i=0;i<balance.length;i++){
            if(  balance >= 1000000){
                System.out.println("the customer is vip"+balance);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("the customer is np"+balance);}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add error logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`balance`is an array.

Writing `balance >= 1000000` makes no sense as you are comparing an int with an array. You are not comparing a value of the table, but the whole table.

Instead use:

```
if(balance[i] >= 1000000){
```